# is there a way to minimize/hide and show the QListWidget in my UI

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

[image]

This is my UI, on the right side I have a QListWidget with 3 items, when I click these items, the corresponding entries on the left side of the UI must be populated , anyways The QListwidget on the right side, i do not want it to be always visible, i want the QListwidget to be minimized usually and show up once the "show options>>" button is clicked, and when i click it again, it should be minimized again,

is there any way to accomplish this using QT Designer or code, what widgets or tools i need to use to get this ?

Answer (score 1):

you can set the visibility to false, this will hide the `listView`

```
ui->myList.setVisible(false);
```

maybe define 1 slot taking a bool var to set the visibility to true or false.

then code the slot of the click of the button so that is calls the slot that hide/show the list!

Comment: Thanks, i can now do the visible, non visible part using a boolean variable , and this hides the qlistwidget perfectly , but kinda clueless how to use the setfixedwidth function to manipulate the dialogs width , this is my code

Comment: after i hide the QListwidget the size of QDialog box remains still same and in the place of QListWidget there is an empty space., that's why i want to change the size of QDialogbox as well.

Answer (score 1):

Connect a slot to `QPushButton::clicked()` "Show Options >>" button  and use `setVisible(true)` on your listwidget.
Connect a slot to `QListWidget::itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)`. This is your place where you can handle which item the user clicked and populate the data. And then, use again `setVisible(false)` function to hide the list.

If you wish to set width of the form, depending of the list appearance, use `setFixedWidth()` of your form to extend it or shrink it. Use `width()` function of your list, get its width and to add it or subtract it from the form's `width()`

Comment: Okay thanks, i can now do the visible, non visible part using a boolean variable , and this hides the qlistwidget perfectly , but kinda clueless how to use the setfixedwidth function to manipulate the dialogs width , this is my code

Comment: `void ValidateTextComd::on_showbutton_clicked()
{
 showing = !showing;
 
 if (showing == false)
 {
  ui.elements_listwidget->setVisible(false);
  
 }
 else
  ui.elements_listwidget->setVisible(true);
}
`

Comment: Hey. it is easy:  void ValidateTextComd::on_showbutton_clicked()  {ui.elements_listwidget->setVisible(! ui.elements_listwidget->isVisible()); }

Comment: i got that part working , the QListwidget hides when i click that button, but i need help with how to manipulate the size of my QDialog when the button is clicked, because as of now when i click the `showbutton` the qlistwidget hides but there is a grey area(empty space) where qlistwidget used to reside , i want to remove this space and hence make my QDialog box smaller using setfixedwidth , how do i do that ?

Comment: finally got it , it was ` window()->setFixedWidth(500);`